# WebBrowser Document is always null

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have this piece of code:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(URL);
HtmlDocument doc = wb.Document;
```

I should mention, that I have no WebBrowser Control on a form, it's just in method in my class.
After this, wb.Document and doc as well are nulls.
Why is that? What do I have to do to obtain this document?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should handle the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and access the document in your event handler when that fires.

Navigation and document loading is handled asynchronously - therefore the control hasn't actually navigated or loaded anything when the `Navigate` method returns; hence why these are null.

Comment: Don't wait, that will deadlock.

Comment: Yeah sorry - I mean *don't access it till the event fires*

Answer (score 2):

It's always null because it hasen't loaded yet.

What you need to do is subscribe to the webBrowser.DocumentCompleted event.