# Inspect Element with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, null, element, document, inspect

I need to get odds on the winamax live betting page. The only problem is that those odds are not present in the HTML code. I have to right click on the odd and click on "inspect element".

The problem is that I have to do it by using C#.
Here is the code

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs#/live");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlElement elm in webBrowser1.Document.All)
    if (elm.GetAttribute("className") == "contestant-name")
        sb2.Append(elm.InnerHtml);
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
doc.Body.InnerHtml = sb2.ToString();
```

When I compile it, it shows me that the webBrowser1.Document is null. There no such HtmlElement.

Does someone have any idea why webBrowser1.Document is null ?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925022/webbrowser-document-is-always-null)

Answer (score -1):

So if I understood, i have to put a function in my EventHandler.
But have I to launch my Navigate before or in my EventHandler ?

I tried this, but a method name is expected in the event handler. I really don't see how to do.

```
public static void wina()
{            

    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs#/live");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(recup(webBrowser1));


}

public static void tryrecup(WebBrowser e)
{

    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in e.Document.All)
        if (elm.GetAttribute("className") == "contestant-name")
            sb2.Append(elm.InnerHtml);
    HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;
    doc.Body.InnerHtml = sb2.ToString();
}
```